# Create an appointment in Microsoft Bookings with any available staff member

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-booking

I am working with Microsoft Bookings to book appointments for a company, but I am using a custom script that creates the appointments instead of the automatically generated bookings page. I can create appointments just fine, but I can't seem to get it to choose the staff member to book automatically, I either have to provide the id of the staff member that I want to book or book it with nobody and pick in the bookings UI. Is there a way to get the api to auto select a staff member to book?

This is the option I want in the API:
[image]

However the API, which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/bookingappointment?view=graph-rest-beta), only allows you to select staff members to book with their IDs, which if no ids are given or if the field is completely left off the request it will just assign no one to the appointment.

Comment: You ever figure this one out?

Comment: No, company I work with is just deciding to move away from Bookings so I have abandoned searching